# What is your overall Yahtzee strategy?

Tags: yahtzee

I have played Yahtzee with people with differing strategies.  Some, I'm not so sure I agree with.

**Roll for 6's every time**
One friend believes that if he tries to roll 6's on every throw, he'll end up with a high 6 roll, sixes for his 3-of-a-kind, 4-of-a-kind, chance, and Yahtzees.

I have found this strategy to blow up in my face all too often; not enough attention is paid to rolls of the lower pips.

**Roll for Yahtzees every throw**
Another friend plays in this mode all the time.  Similar to rolling for 6's, this one is a little better...it incorporates the other pips.  This strategy is a compromise between the first one, and my general strategy:

**Just roll with it**
I find it best to focus on generating Mojo on my first roll, and going wherever the dice point to.  If I'm presented a 2-3-4, or 3-4-5, my mode goes into straights.  If I am presented a collection of the same pips, I focus on trying to get 3+ of the same.  I think it might be most important to get at minimum 3 of each for the top bonus.

Also, on my first roll if I get two pair, especially early in the game, I often pass up going for a full house.  Although I can't back it statistically, I feel it's easy to land a full house in Yahtzee.  This one backfires on me every so often.

**Does anyone have a solid Yahtzee strategy?**

Comment: How is there not a Yahtzee tag...or 'strategy' for that matter

Comment: I added the "yahtzee" tag for you. "Strategy" isn't really a useful tag because it's not a subject people are generally experts in or a useful category for finding questions about a particular topic.

Comment: Voting to close as primarily opinion based (or too broad possibly); this is just going to collect a long list of approaches people use in Yahtzee to varying degrees of success with no correct answer. This is a verbatim "I use \_\_\_\_\_ for \_\_\_\_\_, what do you use?" question from our [Questions to avoid asking](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) help page.